# Handle mouse hover events over a mapped array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add hover events to a group of elements that have been mapped from an array in React. On hover, I would like an element to display or else be hidden. The functionality works at a basic level but it affects every element in the list. How can I make it that it's just the single element being hovered on that has that effect?

```
const [addToCart, setAddToCart] = useState(false);

const showCartHandler = ()=>{
     setAddToCart(true);
}

const hideCartHandler=()=>{
       setAddToCart(false)
}


 {selectedProducts.map((selectedProduct)=>(
               <Chakra.VStack align="start" justify="start">
                  <Chakra.Box position="relative" 
                     onMouseLeave={showCartHandler} onMouseEnter={hideCartHandler}>
                      <Chakra.Image className={Styles.productImage} width= '300px'height="400px" src= 
                        {selectedProduct.image.src} position="relative"/>
                      <Chakra.Button 
                      position="absolute" 
                      bottom="0" width="100%" 
                      left="0" 
                      cursor="pointer" 
                      textTransform="uppercase" 
                      color="white" 
                      background="black" 
                      fontSize="13px" 
                      border="none" 
                      padding="10px"
                      className={Styles.Cart}
                      display={addToCart?'none':'block'}/>
                 ))}
```

Comment: why not managing it through css? it also seems like you should add some more information prefferably code sandbox

Comment: @adirabargil Its two different HTML elements. Image and button. Button should be displayed if Image is hovered on else button should not display. I dont think its possible to do with CSS. It works but it shows button for every image instead of a particular image.

Comment: @ChinomsoJohnson Depending on the HTML structure, CSS should be able to show an image's button and not every button on hover. But again, that would also depend on the HTML structure.

Comment: i would change it to displayed cart state instead... the is a number that represent the hovered data and its value is -1 /null if no hover is active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because this is a list you better change it to indexed active / hovered state and not boolean:

```
const [hoveredCart, setHoveredCart] = useState(-1);

const showCartHandler = (i)=>{
     setHoveredCart(i);
}

const hideCartHandler=()=>{
       setHoveredCart(-1)
}


 {selectedProducts.map((selectedProduct,i)=>(
               <Chakra.VStack align="start" justify="start">
                  <Chakra.Box position="relative" 
                     onMouseLeave={hideCartHandler}
                     onMouseEnter={()=>showCartHandler(i)}>
                      <Chakra.Image className={Styles.productImage} width= '300px'height="400px" src= 
                        {selectedProduct.image.src} position="relative"/>
                      <Chakra.Button 
                      position="absolute" 
                      bottom="0" width="100%" 
                      left="0" 
                      cursor="pointer" 
                      textTransform="uppercase" 
                      color="white" 
                      background="black" 
                      fontSize="13px" 
                      border="none" 
                      padding="10px"
                      className={Styles.Cart}
                      display={hoveredCart === i? 'block':'none'}/>
                 ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this but the button just shows.

Comment: edited.. please try it now... it seems you confused the enter and leave events

Comment: what do you want the button to appear whenever there is hover on the image?

Comment: It works now. Theres a last bit of code you missed on display. It should be  display={hoveredCart === i ? 'block':'none'}. Thank you so much.

Comment: k sorry for that one :)

Answer (score 1):

you can add an index to flag just the row in question

```
const [addToCart, setAddToCart] = useState(false);

const [selectedItemIndex, setSelectedItemIndex] = useState(-1);

const showCartHandler = ()=>{
     setAddToCart(true);
     setSelectedItemIndex(-1);
}

const hideCartHandler=(index)=>()=>{
       setAddToCart(false)
       setSelectedItemIndex(index);
}
//and then modify the boolean expression

 {selectedProducts.map((selectedProduct,index)=>(
               <Chakra.VStack align="start" justify="start">
                  <Chakra.Box position="relative" 
                     onMouseLeave={showCartHandler} onMouseEnter={hideCartHandler(index)}>
                      <Chakra.Image className={Styles.productImage} width= '300px'height="400px" src= 
                        {selectedProduct.image.src} position="relative"/>
                      <Chakra.Button 
                      position="absolute" 
                      bottom="0" width="100%" 
                      left="0" 
                      cursor="pointer" 
                      textTransform="uppercase" 
                      color="white" 
                      background="black" 
                      fontSize="13px" 
                      border="none" 
                      padding="10px"
                      className={Styles.Cart}
                      display={addToCart && selectedItemIndex != index ?'none':'block'}/>
                 ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this but its still the same effect as before

Comment: I think because the logic of events reversed, but anyway your question was answered.