# React hover event activating all elements in map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, hover

I am trying to work with a hover event inline in react as a hook. I am really close, but it's activating ALL items in the `.map`.  I am trying to get it to only fire on the specific `<a>` element that is being hovered on ..

It's a very basic setup:

```
const data = [
    {id: 1, text: 'Inbox Item 1 -- Subject -- Short description', date: '1.03.2016'},
    {id: 2, text: 'Inbox Item 2 -- Subject -- Short description', date: '23.01.2017'},
    {id: 3, text: 'Inbox Item 3 -- Subject -- Short description', date: '12.01.2022'}
];

const inboxItemStyle = ({hover}) => ({
    display: "block",
    borderBottom: '1px solid #CCC',
    backgroundColor: hover ? '#EEF' : '#FFF',
    padding:"15px",
})

function Inbox() {
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
    return (
      <div className="list-group">
        {
         data.map((item) =>
          <SwipeToDelete key={item.id}>
            <a style={inboxItemStyle({hover})}
               onPointerOver={()=> setHover(true)}
               onPointerOut={() => setHover(false)}
            >
              <h4 className="list-group-item-heading">{item.date}</h4>
              <p className="list-group-item-text">{item.text}</p>
            </a>
          </SwipeToDelete>
         )
       }
      </div>
    );
}
export default Inbox;
```

This is what's happening:

[image]

This is my expected result:

[image]

Why is it enabling hover on ALL `<a>` elements?  Isn't the `.map` separating them into individual objects?  Where am I going wrong?

**I tried using index based hooks as well from [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501705/handle-mouse-hover-events-over-a-mapped-array-in-react)**

But the hover ceases to work altogether with this functionality.  What Am I doing wrong?

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(-1);

const showHandler = (i)=>{
    setHover(i);
}

const hideHandler=()=>{
    setHover(-1)
}

return (
   
<div className="list-group">
   {
    data.map((item, i) => (
       <SwipeToDelete key={item.id}>
           <a style={setInboxItemStyle({hover})}
               onMouseLeave={hideHandler}
                onMouseEnter={()=>showHandler(i)}
                 >
           <h4 className="list-group-item-heading">{item.date}</h4>
           <p className="list-group-item-text">{item.text}</p>
           </a>
       </SwipeToDelete>
    ))
   }
</div>
          
);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this simplification of your code:

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)
return (
<>
  <Element1 />
  <Element2 />
  <Element3 />
</>
```

Do you see the problem? - all 3 Elements are accesing the same state. If you hover over any of them you setHover(true) and since there is only this one state which is shared between all Elements you can't distinguish which Element is the one that is hovered over.

So to fix this problem, each Element needs their own state.

I would just create a new component (which is the repeated Element) and in that component you could have a state or hover. That way each repeated element would have their own state. So something like this:

```
function mappedElement (item) {
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)
return (
<SwipeToDelete key={item.id}>
  <a
    style={inboxItemStyle({ hover })}
    onPointerOver={() => setHover(true)}
    onPointerOut={() => setHover(false)}
  >
    <h4 className="list-group-item-heading">{item.date}</h4>
    <p className="list-group-item-text">{item.text}</p>
  </a>
</SwipeToDelete>;
)}
```

and then your map would look something like this:

```
data.map(item => <mappedElement item={item} />)
```

The index based hook would also be a possible solution, I guess there is an issue with the style function (inBoxItemStyle) - since now `hover` isn't storing information on weather or not something is hovered on anymore but on which element is being hovered on you'd have to rewrite that function/style to consider that change

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a case of event bubbling. Try this:

```
<a style={setInboxItemStyle({hover})}
         onMouseLeave={hideHandler}
         onMouseEnter={(e)=>showHandler(e, i)}
             >
       ...
</a>
```

And then in your handler:

```
const showHandler = (e, i) => {
e.stopPropagation();
setHover(i);
}
```

Comment: since the problem is between siblings (not child and parent) propagation is probably not at fault here

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more answer, this i have  implemented in my react code with mui css,

```
    <List>
            {SidebarIcons.map((item, index) => (
                            <ListItem key={index} disablePadding>
                                <ListItemIconStyle>
                                    <Link href={item.href}>
                                        <Grid
                                            className={classes.iconHover}
                                            sx={{
                                                color: '#FFF',
                                                '&:hover': {
                                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    color: item.color,
                                                },
                                            }}
                                        >
                                            <Icon icon={item.icon} width={30} height={30} />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Link>
                                </ListItemIconStyle>
                            </ListItem>
                        ))}
                    </List>
```